# A dictionary in a Pandas dataframe column in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I am reading a csv file that a column contains a multi keys dict. Here is an example:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3], 'b':[{'AUS': {'arv': '10:00', 'vol': 5}, 'DAL': {'arv': '9:00', 'vol': 1}}, {'DAL': {'arv': '10:00', 'vol': 6}, 'NYU': {'arv': '10:00', 'vol': 3}}, {'DAL': {'arv': '8:00', 'vol': 6}, 'DAL': {'arv': '10:00', 'vol': 1}, 'GBD': {'arv': '12:00', 'vol': 1}}]})
```

What I am trying to do is perform a query on the column b of the above dataframe and return the corresponding values as presented in the following. However, I am trying to see if there is a more intuitive and more efficient way to perform similar operations in a large dataset without looping through the dict.

```
#convert column b of df to a dict
df_dict = df.b.to_dict()
print(df_dict)
{0: {'AUS': {'arv': '10:00', 'vol': 5}, 'DAL': {'arv': '9:00', 'vol': 1}}, 1: {'DAL': {'arv': '10:00', 'vol': 6}, 'NYU': {'arv': '10:00', 'vol': 3}}, 2: {'DAL': {'arv': '10:00', 'vol': 1}, 'GBD': {'arv': '12:00', 'vol': 1}}}

def get_value(my_str, my_time):
    total = 0
    for key in df_dict:
        if my_str in df_dict[key].keys():
            if df_dict[key].get(my_str).get('arv') == my_time:
                total = total + df_dict[key].get(my_str).get('vol')
    return total

print("total vol is at 10:00 is: ", get_value('DAL', '10:00'))
total vol is at 10:00 is:  7
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While dukkee's answer works, I believe if you want to manipulate your dataframe in other ways his organization is a bit counterintuitive. I would also reorganize the dataframe, though this way:

```
input_data = {
    'a':[1,2,3], 
    'b':[{'AUS': {'arv': '10:00', 'vol': 5},
         'DAL': {'arv': '9:00', 'vol': 1}
        },
        {'DAL': {'arv': '10:00', 'vol': 6},
         'NYU': {'arv': '10:00', 'vol': 3}
        },
        {'DAL': {'arv': '8:00', 'vol': 6},
         'DAL': {'arv': '10:00', 'vol': 1},
         'GBD': {'arv': '12:00', 'vol': 1}
        }]
}

data_list = [[input_data['a'][i], key, value['arv'], value['vol']]
            for i, dic in enumerate(input_data['b'])
            for key, value in dic.items()]
df = pd.DataFrame(data_list, columns=['a', 'abr', 'arv', 'vol'])
```

Which results in:

```
>>> df
   a  abr    arv  vol
0  1  AUS  10:00    5
1  1  DAL   9:00    1
2  2  DAL  10:00    6
3  2  NYU  10:00    3
4  3  DAL  10:00    1
5  3  GBD  12:00    1
```

I believe that's the way you should organize your data. Having dictionaries as values in a dataframe seems counterintuitive to me. This way you can use `loc` to solve your problem:

```
>>> df.loc[(df['arv']=='10:00') & (df['abr']=='DAL')]
   a  abr    arv  vol
2  2  DAL  10:00    6
4  3  DAL  10:00    1
>>> vol_sum = sum(df.loc[(df['arv']=='10:00') & (df['abr']=='DAL')]['vol'])
>>> print(f"total vol at 10:00 is: {vol_sum}")
"total vol at 10:00 is: 7"
```

Little plus compared to dukkee: no need to use collections, and list comprehensions are faster than for-loops! Note that in one of your dictionaries you have two times `'DAL'` as a key, so the first one gets erased.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to reorganize your data presentation in DataFrame:

```py
>>> from collections import defaultdict, Counter
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> input_data = {0: {"AUS": {"arv": "10:00", "vol": 5}, "DAL": {"arv": "9:00", "vol": 1}}, 1: {"DAL": {"arv": "10:00", "vol": 6}, "NYU": {"arv": "10:00", "vol": 3}}, 2: {"DAL": {"arv": "10:00", "vol": 1}, "GBD": {"arv": "12:00", "vol": 1}}}
>>> data = defaultdict(Counter)
>>> for value in input_data.values():
...     for name in value:
...         data[value[name]["arv"]][name] = value[name]["vol"]
... 
>>> data
defaultdict(<class "collections.Counter">, {"10:00": Counter({"DAL": 7, "AUS": 5, "NYU": 3}), "9:00": Counter({"DAL": 1}), "12:00": Counter({"GBD": 1})})
>>> frame = pd.DataFrame(data).T
>>> frame
       AUS  DAL  NYU  GBD
10:00  5.0  7.0  3.0  NaN
9:00   NaN  1.0  NaN  NaN
12:00  NaN  NaN  NaN  1.0
>>> frame[frame.index == "10:00"]["DAL"]
10:00    7.0
Name: DAL, dtype: float64
```